# The template class type only work in basic type not work in class type

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I wrote a template class but it just works for `int`, `double` and does not work for my own class. The code is as follows:

```
/*OrderedList.h*/
namespace MYLIB
{
    class Student
    {
    public:
        display();

    private:
        char* snum;
        char* name;
        char* email;
    };

    template<class T>
    class OrderedList
    {
    public:
        OrderedList() :head(), tail(), size(0) {}
        ~OrderedList(){}

    private:
        ......
    };
}

/*main.cpp*/
#include "OrderedList.h"

int main()
{
    MYLIB::OrderedList<int> listi;
    MYLIB::OrderedList<double> listd;
    MYLIB::OrderedList<Student> lists;
}
```

The error message I get is: `'Error: Student is not defined.'` Thank you for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Student` is defined in the `MYLIB` namespace, just like class template `OrderedList`. So you need

```
MYLIB::OrderedList<MYLIB::Student>
```